# Pytorch Neural Network returns the same value for each set of inputs in my batch

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network

I am defining a physics informed neural network using pytorch to estimate values of h and q corresponding to inputs of distance, x and time, t. I am encountering a problem that my neural network only outputs 1 value of h and one value of q for every value in my batch.

The output value changes for each iteration and the loss value reduces which indicates the training loop is working. I think the way the data is pre-processed or the neural network architecture is incorrectly coded which results in this error

Output from training step 0 and 1000, showing the values changing

[image: Output from iteration 1] [image]

my neural network architecture is defined as followed:

```
class FCN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, N_INPUT, N_OUTPUT, N_HIDDEN, N_LAYERS):
    super().__init__()
    activation = nn.Tanh
    self.fcs = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(N_INPUT, N_HIDDEN),
        activation()
    )
    self.fch = nn.Sequential(*[
        nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(N_HIDDEN, N_HIDDEN),
            activation()
        ) for _ in range(N_LAYERS - 1)
    ])
    self.fce = nn.Linear(N_HIDDEN, N_OUTPUT)  # Output layer

def forward(self, x, t):
    inputs = torch.cat([x, t], axis = 1)
    inputs = self.fcs(inputs)
    inputs = self.fch(inputs)
    outputs = self.fce(inputs)
    return outputs

pinn = FCN(2, 2, 9, 12)
```

The inputs x_colloc and t_colloc are given as

```
x_colloc = torch.linspace(0, 300, 500).view(-1,1).requires_grad_(True)
t_colloc = torch.linspace(0, 10, 500).view(-1,1).requires_grad_(True)
```

To reiterate the issue, the inputs here are values ranging from 0 to 300 for distance x and 0 to 10 for time t. For each iteration they always output the same values across the batch size as shown in the graphs above.

The training loop is defined as follows

```
for i in range (200000):

   optimiser.zero_grad()

   colloc_output = pinn(x_colloc, t_colloc)

   h_hat, q_hat = colloc_output[:,0], colloc_output[:,1]
   dq_dt = torch.autograd.grad(q_hat, t_colloc, 
   torch.ones_like(q_hat), create_graph=True)[0]
   dq_dx = torch.autograd.grad(q_hat, x_colloc, 
   torch.ones_like(q_hat), create_graph=True)[0]
   dh_dt = torch.autograd.grad(h_hat, t_colloc, 
   torch.ones_like(h_hat), create_graph=True)[0]
   dh_dx = torch.autograd.grad(h_hat, x_colloc, 
   torch.ones_like(h_hat), create_graph=True)[0]

   F1 = Cs_A * dq_dt + q_hat * dq_dx + g * Cs_A**2 * dh_dx + f * 
   (torch.abs(q_hat) * q_hat) / (2 * diam)
   F2 = Cs_A * dh_dt + q_hat * dh_dx + a**2/g * dq_dx

   loss_pde = torch.mean(F1**2 + F2**2)

   train_output = pinn(x_train_rand, t_train_rand)

   loss_data = torch.mean((hq_tr - 
   torch.squeeze(train_output))**2)

   loss = w_f * loss_pde + loss_data

   loss.backward()
   optimiser.step()
```

The question has been edited to show the loss function in full
The inputs to the full loss function are as follows:

```
x_train = torch.tensor(x_inp.values).to(dtype=torch.float32)
t_train = torch.tensor(t_inp.values).to(dtype=torch.float32)
h_train = torch.tensor(h_inp.values).to(dtype=torch.float32)
q_train = torch.tensor(q_inp.values).to(dtype=torch.float32)

n_samples = len(x_train)
perm_indicies = torch.randperm(n_samples)

x_train_rand = x_train[perm_indicies].view(-1,1)
t_train_rand = t_train[perm_indicies].view(-1,1)
h_train_rand = h_train[perm_indicies].view(-1,1)
q_train_rand = q_train[perm_indicies].view(-1,1)
```

Any help is appreciated! if you would like anymore information please let me know and I will be happy to provide, thanks again.

Comment: The loss function that you avoided to write is very probably the cause of the problem.. Please edit the question and include it.

Comment: @cp I have now edited the question to show the loss function in full. Thanks again